# Re-use buttons jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, onclick, unbind

I have 2 buttons which each one appears after an AJAX call. This is the code which work in these buttons:

```
 $('#detalles').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('estatus');
    var val = $(this).val();
    estatusObj[id](val);
});
```

And estatusObj have the next:

```
etc...
'4': function(val) {
        if (val === 'no') {
            if (confirm('¿Desea eliminar la oportunidad ' + nombre + '?')) {
                $.post('oportunidad_query.php', {'id': oportunidad, 'accion': 'delete'})
                        .done(function() {
                            $('#detalles').on('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
                                location.reload();
                            });
                            $('#detalles').dialog({buttons: {'Cerrar': function() {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }}
                            }).html('<h3>¡' + nombre + ' eliminado!</h3>');
                        });
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('hola');
            $('#detalles section:first-of-type p+p').html('¿Ajustar cotización?');
            $('#detalles').off('click', 'button', function() {
                alert('Lo hizo');
            });
        }
    },
```

The buttons says 'Yes' and 'No'. If 'No', delete data into the database (this works).
But when click 'Yes', I want to keep those buttons, but with differents click events. 
How can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(val) {
    if($('#detalles button').attr('rel')=='second'){
        if (val === 'no') {
            alert("Second No");
        }else{
            alert("Second yes");
        }
    }else{
        if (val === 'no') {
            if (confirm('¿Desea eliminar la oportunidad ' + nombre + '?')) {
                $.post('oportunidad_query.php', {
                    'id': oportunidad, 
                    'accion': 'delete'
                })
                .done(function() {
                    $('#detalles').on('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
                        location.reload();
                    });
                    $('#detalles').dialog({
                        buttons: {
                            'Cerrar': function() {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    }).html('<h3>¡' + nombre + ' eliminado!</h3>');
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('hola');
            //$('#detalles section:first-of-type p+p').html('¿Ajustar cotización?');
            $('#detalles button').attr('rel','second');
        }
    }

}
```

You can add some attribute rel into buttons element.

Comment: It works! :D
Now, can u give a reference, explanation or example about the attribute `rel` in the buttons?

Comment: We can use any name as attribute. but rel is mostly used for links etc. so I have given that name.

Comment: Thank u so much for the answer. I think that if I want something official we should use attribute `data`.